# Kendo grid dropdown issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a view with tabs and each tab has a  kendo grid with inline edit and have dropdown inside the grid. Problem which i am facing is when i update the value of the drop down is not showing the updated value but when i refresh the  page the updated value is showing. But if i refresh the problem here is if i update the value is the sceond tab it i do refresh it will go to second tab. Is there any way I can acheive this without refesh.

```
    @model BHI.TESQ.Entities.Interfaces.Models.ILocationAdminModel
@if (TempData["Result"] == "Data Saved Successfully")
{
    <script>
        alert('Location Data Saved Successfully');
    </script>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveLocationAdmin", "Administration", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div style="margin-top: 45px;height:400px">
        <h5 class="page-header k-block k-primary" style="overflow: hidden; margin-left: 5px; max-width: 1133px;">@ViewBag.Title</h5>

        <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0px">

            <tr style="margin-top: 0px;">
                <td>
                    @*<table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>*@
                    @(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
                    .Name("vertical")
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:400px" })
                    .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Horizontal)
                    .Panes(verticalPanes =>
                     {
                         verticalPanes.Add()
                             .Size("150px")
                              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:400px" })
                             .Scrollable(false)
                             .Resizable(false)
                             .Content(Html.Action("AdminLinks").ToString());

                         verticalPanes.Add()
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "top-pane" })
                         .Scrollable(false)
                         .Collapsible(false)
                         .Content(

                           Html.Kendo().Splitter()
                               .Name("horizontal")
                               .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:400px" })
                               .Panes(horizontalPanes =>
                               {

                                   horizontalPanes.Add()
                                       .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "left-pane" })
                                       .Size("300px")
                                       .Collapsible(true)

                                       .Resizable(false)
                                       .Content(@<div class="pane-content">
                                        <h6 class="header k-block">Create New Location</h6>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="td-style">Location Name<span class="asterisk_input"></span></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input id="txtLocName" name="txtLocName" type="text" class="textbox" required />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="td-style">Country<span class="asterisk_input"></span></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                                .Name("ddCountry")
                                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required" })
                                                            //.BindTo(new List<string>() {
                                                            //      "United States",
                                                            //      "United Kingdom (UK)",
                                                            //                })
                                                .BindTo(@Model.Country)
                                                .OptionLabel("--Select Country--")
                                                .DataTextField("CountryName")
                                                .DataValueField("CountryId")
                                                .Events(e => e.Change("OnCountryChange"))
                                                    )
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="hddCountry" name="hddCountry" value="" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="td-style">State</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                                .Name("ddState")
                                                .OptionLabel("--Select State--")
                                                .DataTextField("StateName")
                                                .DataValueField("StateId")
                                                .Events(e => e.Change("OnStateChange"))
                                                            //.BindTo(new List<string>() {
                                                            //      "Texas",
                                                            //    })
                                                .DataSource(source =>
                                                    {
                                                        source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetStateList", "Administration").Data("filterState"); }).ServerFiltering(true);
                                                    })
                                                .Enable(false)
                                                .AutoBind(false)
                                                .CascadeFrom("ddCountry")
                                                    )
                                                    <script>
                                                        function filterState() {
                                                            return {
                                                                countryId: $("#ddCountry").val()
                                                            };
                                                        }
                                                    </script>
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="hddState" name="hddState" value="" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="td-style">Location Status<span class="asterisk_input"></span></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @*@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                                                        .Name("ddLocStatus")
                                                        .BindTo(new List<string>() {
                                                              "Active",
                                                              "In-Active",
                                                                        })
                                                            )*@
                                                    <input id="chkBoxStatus" type="checkbox" name="chkBoxStatus" value="true" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
            .Name("btnInsert")
            .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClick"))
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "submit", @class = "btn btn-primary button" })
            .Content("Save"))

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
            .Name("btnCancel")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-primary button" })
            .Content("Cancel"))
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                            );

                                   horizontalPanes.Add()
                                       .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "center-pane" })
                                       .Scrollable(false)
                                       .Content(@<div>
                                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Locations)
                                            .Name("Grid")
                                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "min-height:400px" })
                                            .Columns(columns =>
                                            {
                                                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-primary button" }); }).Width(100);
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.LocationId).Width(140).Hidden(true);
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.LocationName).Width(140);
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.CountryId).EditorTemplateName("CountryNames").Title("CountryName").ClientTemplate("#:CountryName#").Width(150);
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.StateId).EditorTemplateName("StateNames").Title("StateName").ClientTemplate("#:StateName#").Width(150);
                                                columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive).Width(100);
                                            })

                                            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
                                            .Pageable()
                                            .Navigatable()
                                            .Sortable()
                                            .Scrollable()
                                            .Groupable()
                                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                            .Ajax()
                                            .PageSize(20)
                                            .ServerOperation(false)
                                            .Events(events => { events.Error("error_handler"); events.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"); })
                                            .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.LocationId); model.Field(p => p.LocationId).Editable(false); })
                                            .Update(update => update.Action("Update_Location", "Administration"))

                                            )
                                        )

                                    </div>
                            );

                               }).ToHtmlString()
                  );

                     })
                    )

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        @*</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        *@
    </div>
}
<style scoped>
    #vertical {
        width: 95%;
    }

    .pane-content {
        width: 300px;
    }

    div.k-grid-content {
        min-height: 300px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function error_handler(e) {
        if (e.errors) {
            var message = "Errors:\n";
            $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                if ('errors' in value) {
                    $.each(value.errors, function () {
                        message += this + "\n";
                    });
                }
            });
            alert(message);
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.cancelChanges();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnCancel').click(function () {
            $(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('')
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked')
            var dropdownlist = $("#ddCountry").data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdownlist.select(0);
            var dropdownlist = $("#ddState").data("kendoDropDownList");
            dropdownlist.select(0);
        });
    });

    function onClick(e) {
        var locationName = $("#txtLocName").val();
        if (locationName != "") {
            var selectedText = $("#ddCountry").data("kendoDropDownList").text();
            if (selectedText == "--Select Country--") {
                alert('Please select country');
            }
        }
    }
    function OnCountryChange(e) {
        var selectedText = $("#ddCountry").data("kendoDropDownList").text()
        $("#hddCountry").val(selectedText);
    }

    function OnStateChange(e) {
        var selectedText = $("#ddState").data("kendoDropDownList").text()
        $("#hddState").val(selectedText);
    }

    function onRequestEnd(e) {
        if (e.type == "create" || e.type == "update") {
            if (e.response == null || e.response.Errors == null) {
                alert("Location Data Updated Successfully");
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Team,Can someone quickly help me on this?

Comment: any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: When you are saving the values from the grid what are you passing back as the result from the operation? This will help with one possible solution I have.

Comment: public ActionResult Update_Parameter([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Parameter UpdatedParameter)
        {
         mTestAdminLogic.SaveModel((ITestAdminModel)model, ViewBag.ApplicationId, Operation.UpdateParameter);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ParameterUpdateError", ex.Message);
                
            }
            return RedirectToAction("TestAdmin");
        }

Comment: this is what i have written in my update function

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So taking your code sample and assuming a couple of things:

Your code:

```
public ActionResult Update_Parameter([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Parameter UpdatedParameter)
        {
            try
            {
                mTestAdminLogic.SaveModel((ITestAdminModel)model, ViewBag.ApplicationId, Operation.UpdateParameter);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ParameterUpdateError", ex.Message);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("TestAdmin");
        }
```

and these are my changes:

```
 public JsonResult Update_Parameter([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Parameter UpdatedParameter)
        {
            var returnModel = {your return model here}; 
            try
            {
              returnModel =  mTestAdminLogic.SaveModel((ITestAdminModel)model, ViewBag.ApplicationId, Operation.UpdateParameter);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ParameterUpdateError", ex.Message);
            }
            return Json(new[] { returnModel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
```

So let me explain.

If this action is only being used to update the Grid then change it to a `JsonResult` as the result of the grid update will be expecting JSON back.

I am assuming you have left our the declaration of your `Data Layer` logic and have cut it down to this single line:

```
 mTestAdminLogic.SaveModel((ITestAdminModel)model, ViewBag.ApplicationId, Operation.UpdateParameter);
```

now if this model is different to the one expected by the grid the resulting action of this line should return back the appropriate model that the grid is expecting. As you have not declared that in your grid I am assuming it is some kind of LocationBasedModel.

Now once this update has completed then you should be returning back the appropriate model and adding the following **Using** statement `using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;` this will give you access to the **.ToDataSourceResult()** extension method which will then allow you to transform this single model back to the grid and let the grid update its view of the data. Including the request and modelstate will also provide any errors and apply any existing filtering etc. back to the grid.

This would resolve the issue with the page "refreshing" itself everytime this action is called.

Any issues let me know and I will update my answer to reflect any changes you need.

Comment: When I do savemodel i am returning some Id back. How can i return the model?

Comment: What does the ID refer to. Is it the object being bound to the grid? If it is just return back the object that is created that has this Id.

Comment: Id refers to successfully updated or not into database.

Comment: If this method is being used specifically for updating the grid and then rebinding back to the grid then it should be returning the grid's model and not the id. If you don't want to change this code then you could add a $("grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read() after the successful update in your onRequestEnd js method.

Comment: $("GridParam").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read() is coming as null on request end

Comment: I have pasted the whole code which i have done above. Please see if any correction has to be done to resolve the null issue onrequest end.

Comment: well you have to give jquery the element name so in your case $('#grid').  But as you have no read command on this grid it will return null as it has nothing to bind the read action too. I would suggest adding a read function onto the grid or changing the returning type of the update method to the model that is bound to the grid.

Comment: Okay fine. I will with retuning a model.If i face any issue i will get back to you.Thanks....

Comment: Hi David, could you please help on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334829/kendo-chart-rendering-very-slow